# Problema com hover

Tags: html, css

Estou iniciando meus estudos em html/css então baixei um layout pra tentar desenvolver. tô numa parte do site que é como uma galeria de fotos, eu consegui fazer exatamente o que queria, porém, tive um problema com o hover.

O que deveria acontecer era: você passa o mouse pela imagem e aparece sua descrição.

O problema é que mesmo com o mouse em cima do list item, a descrição some.

Aqui está o código: https://jsfiddle.net/o6sv6cec/

HTML

```
<section class="works">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="our-works">
            <h2 class="title-section">Our Works</h2>
            <ul class="list-works">
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                        <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <a class="item-works" href="#">
                   <img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                      <div class="desc-works">
                       <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> 
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item-works"><img src="image/work1.png" alt="Work" class="img-works">
                    <div class="sub-works">
                       <div class="desc-works">
                        <h2 class="subtitle">Work</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.item-works {
    z-index: 99999;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height: 8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.item-works:hover .sub-works {
    display: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item-works:hover .sub-works {
    animation-name: hoverwork;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.sub-works {
    display: none;
    height: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #00aeff;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.desc-works {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.desc-works p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-works {
    max-width: 100%;   
}

@keyframes hoverwork {
    0% {height: 0;}
    50% {height: 100%;}
    75% {height: 95%}
    100% {height: 100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua classe `CSS` `.item-works:hover .sub-works` você pode usar `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` para persistir o estado final.

```
.item-works:hover .sub-works {
    animation-name: hoverwork;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: você saberia me dizer se ao retirar o mouse tem como o efeito ser o contrário? no momento eu tiro o mouse ele simplesmente some o fundo.

Comment: @FábioMendes Da uma olhada na implementação do animation, talvez tenha alguma coisa relacionada :)

Comment: @FábioMendes Caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido seu problema, favor marca-lá como correta.